# Bones aren't grouped perfectly when I rotate them two times on the X axis

Tags: modeling, rigging, bones

I'm rigging the foot of the bird Piero training course of the CG Cookie and I get stuck on episode `26 : piero rigging leg`. The author has selected all the bones of the foot and he rotates them on the X axis two times and the fingers are grouped perfectly,but it does not happen to me. Why ? Added two screenshots.

[image: foot fingers grouped perfectly]

[image: what happens to my bird]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution to this problem by myself. I have to rotate the z axis on the top.